# VSCode C++ automatic aligning of else with if and no braces around else for single statement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I have a simple `if/else` construct with both having single statements within. `if` case correctly does not default to automatic `{}`, while `else` (unfortunately, in my view) does.

Also, unless the user manually formats the code selection, (either by Ctrl-K Ctrl F, or else Ctrl-Shift-i), correct formatting does not happen. See gif below.

[image]

My formatting settings in `settings.json` currently are:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}",
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

Is there a way to:

(1) by default set the `else` NOT to provide a `{/* code */}` block.

(2) have the `else` align vertically with the `if` without having to manually force formatting of the selection.

Comment: issue related to this and `VcFormat` ultimately led to a resolution thus: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6561